# Cannot advance slide in jupyter notebook converted to Reveal.js slides

Tags: jupyter-notebook, reveal.js, jupyter-lab, nbconvert

I am trying to convert my notebook, created with jupyter lab, to Reveal.js slides.

I am using this command:

`jupyter nbconvert Initial-Data-Exploration.ipynb --to slides --post serve`

taken from [this Github issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4067).

However I am getting the same issue as the original reporter: I only see the first slide and cannot advance to subsequent slides.

In the browser console, I am seeing this error:

[image]

Which I assume refers to a `custom.css` file that I could use to optionally customize the appearance of the slides and not related to the functionality.

The only errors I see on the command-line are these:

> WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 1.05ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.90ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.88ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /style.min.css.map (127.0.0.1) 1.32ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.69ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.87ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /style.min.css.map (127.0.0.1) 1.02ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (127.0.0.1) 0.93ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.82ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /custom.css (127.0.0.1) 0.73ms
>   WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /style.min.css.map (127.0.0.1) 0.82ms

which I assume refer to the same issue as above and also won't impact functionality.

I'm new to using `nbconvert` and `reveal.js` so any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: this seems to only be a problem when using Jupyter Lab and does not appear when using regular jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Have you ever figured this out? I came across the same issue there and found your question. No solutions - I just wanted to check out this fancy slides thing :(

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue. In Jupyter go to **View → Show Right Sidebar** and set the **Slide Type** for each slide.

The problem is when the "cell type" is undefined by default.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same. A bit of a workaround for me was [pip installing RISE](https://rise.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html), in the jupyter notebook. Then I could render the slides directly in the notebook and, after downloading as a .slides.html, finally open it in a browser and see the slides.